# Converting several bytes in an array to another type in Go

Tags: go, casting, arrays

I just started yesterday with Go so I apologise in advance for the silly question.

Imagine that I have a byte array such as:

```
func main(){
    arrayOfBytes := [10]byte{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
}
```

Now what if I felt like taking the first four bytes of that array and using it as an integer? Or perhaps I have a struct that looks like this:

```
type eightByteType struct {
    a uint32
    b uint32
}
```

Can I easily take the first 8 bytes of my array and turn it into an object of type eightByteType?

I realise these are two different questions but I think they may have similar answers. I've looked through the documentation and haven't seen a good example to achieve this.

Being able to cast a block of bytes to anything is one of the things I really like about C. Hopefully I can still do it in Go.

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53429894/12817546 and this https://play.golang.org/p/IYpv3YJsZO5 answer your question in part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [`encoding/binary`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary), as well as [`bytes.Buffer`](http://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer)

TL;DR version:

```
import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "bytes"
)

func main() {
    var s eightByteType
    binary.Read(bytes.NewBuffer(array[:]), binary.LittleEndian, &s)
}
```

A few things to note here: we pass array[:], alternatively you could declare your array as a slice instead (`[]byte{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`) and let the compiler worry about sizes, etc, and `eightByteType` won't work as is (IIRC) because `binary.Read` won't touch private fields. This would work:

```
type eightByteType struct {
    A, B uint32
}
```

Comment: Does this code actually copy data from the array to the struct?

Comment: @ithkuil what do you mean? Actually copy as opposed to what?

Comment: as opposed to what you can do in C, cast a bytearray to a struct, so that the struct uses the same memory region occupied by the bytearray without copying. This was my interpretation of the last part of the question: "Being able to cast a block of bytes to anything is one of the things I really like about C. Hopefully I can still do it in Go."

Comment: @ithkuil in that case you need to use package `unsafe`